# Custom keras callbacks and changing weight (beta) of regularization term in variational autoencoder loss function

Tags: keras, tensorflow, loss-function, autoencoder

The variational autoencoder loss function is this: Loss = Loss_reconstruction + Beta * Loss_kld. I am trying to efficiently implement [Kullback-Liebler Divergence Cyclic Annealing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10145)--that is changing the weight of beta dynamically during training. I subclass the `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` class as a start, **but I don't know how I can update a `tf.keras.Model` variable from a custom keras callback.** Furthermore, I would like to track how the betas change at the end of each training step (`on_train_batch_end`), and right now I have a list in the callback class, but I know python lists don't play well with TensorFlow. When I fit the model, I get a warning that my `on_train_batch_end` function is slower than the processing of the batch itself. **I think I should use a  `tf.TensorArray` instead of python lists, but then the `tf.TensorArray` method `write` cannot use a `tf.Variable` for the index (i.e., as the number of steps changes, the index in the `tf.TensorArray` to which a new beta for that step should be written changes)... is there a better way to store value changes?** It looks like this [github](https://github.com/hoangcuong2011/UsefulScripts/blob/fece43754ff1e2fa9ee71cbad38f74ef60fe78cb/%5BHalf%5D%20KL%20annealing.md) shows a solution that doesn't involve a custom `tf.keras.Model` and that uses a different kind of KL annealing. Below is a callback function and dummy VAE.

```py
class CyclicAnnealing(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  """Cyclic annealing from https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.10145
  
  Requires that model tracks training iterations and 
  total number of training iterations. It also requires
  that model has hyperparameter for `M` and `R`.
  """

  def __init__(self, schedule_fxn='sigmoid', **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    # INEFFICIENT WAY OF LOGGING `betas` AND THE TRAIN STEPS...
    # The `train_iterations` list could be removed because in principle
    # if I have a list of betas, I know that the list of betas is of length
    # (number of samples//batch size) * number of epochs.
    # This is because (number of samples//batch size) * number of epochs is the total number of steps for the model.
    self.betas = []
    self.train_iterations = []

    if schedule_fxn == 'sigmoid':
      self.schedule_fxn = self.sigmoid

    elif schedule_fxn =='linear':
      self.schedule_fxn = self.linear

    else:
      raise ValueError('Invalid arg: `schedule_fxn`')

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    print('\nCurrent anneal weight B =', self.beta)

  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    """Computes betas and updates list"""

    # Compute beta
    self.beta = self.beta_tau_cyclic_annealing(self.compute_tau())

    ###################################
    # HOW TO UPDATE BETA IN THE MODEL???
    ###################################

    # Update the lists for logging
    self.betas.append(self.beta)
    self.train_iterations.append(self.model._train_counter))

  def get_annealing_data(self):
    return {'betas': self.betas, 'training_iterations': self.train_iterations}

  def sigmoid(self, x):
    """Monotonic increasing function
    
    :return: tf.constant float32
    """

    return (1/(1+tf.keras.backend.exp(-x)))

  def linear(self, x):
    return x/self.model._R

  def compute_tau(self):
    """Used to determine kld_beta.
    
    :return: tf.constant float32
    """

    t = tf.identity(self.model._train_counter)
    T = self.model._total_training_iterations
    M = self.model._M
    numerator = tf.cast(tf.math.floormod(tf.subtract(t, 1), tf.math.floordiv(T, M)), dtype=tf.float32)
    denominator = tf.cast(tf.math.floordiv(T, M), dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.math.divide(numerator, denominator)

  def beta_tau_cyclic_annealing(self, tau):
    """Compute change for kld_beta.
    
    :param tau: Increases beta_tau
    :param R: Proportion used to increase Beta w/i cycle.

    :return: tf.constant float32
    """

    R = self.model._R
    if tau <= R:
        return self.schedule_fxn(tau)
    else:
      return tf.constant(1.0)
```

Dummy vae:

````py
class VAE(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_samples, batch_size, epochs, features, units, latent_size, kld_beta, M, R, **kwargs):
        """Defines state for model.

        :param num_samples: <class 'int'>
        :param batch_size: <class 'int'>
        :param epochs: <class 'int'>
        :param features: <class 'int'> if input is (n, m), then `features` is the the `m` dimension. This param is used with the decoder.
        :param units: <class 'int'> Number of hidden units.
        :param latent_size: <class 'int'> Dimension of latent space z.
        :param kld_beta: <tf.Variable??> for dynamic weight.
        :param M: <class 'int'> Hyperparameter for cyclic annealing.
        :param R: <class 'float'> Hyperparameter for cyclic annealing.
        """
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # NEED TO UPDATE THIS SOMEHOW -- I think it should be a tf.Variable?
        self.kld_beta = kld_beta

        # Hyperparameters for CyclicAnnealing
        self._M = M
        self._R = R
        self._total_training_iterations = (num_samples//batch_size) * epochs    

        # Encoder and Decoder not defined, but typically
        # encoder = inputs -> dense -> dense mu and dense log var -> z
        # while decoder = z -> dense -> reconstructions
        self.encoder = Encoder(units, latent_size)
        self.decoder = Decoder(features)

    def call(self, inputs):
        z, mus, log_vars = self.encoder(inputs)
        reconstructions = self.decoder(z)

        kl_loss = self.compute_kl_loss(mus, log_vars)

        # THE BETA WEIGHT NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC
        weighted_kl_loss = self.kld_beta * kl_loss
      
        self.add_loss(weighted_kl_loss)

        return reconstructions
        
    def compute_kl_loss(self, mus, log_vars):
         return -0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(1. + log_vars - tf.exp(log_vars) - tf.pow(mus, 2))
```
````